# backbone custom events: getting caller object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Just a bit of trivia;
I'm creating views and models in a loop then trying to bind custom events to them. All goo so far but what about when I want to find out with object fired the event. I know there are other longer winded ways to individually assign events to each one in series but I guess I'm looking for a more efficient way:

```
initialize: function(args)
    {
        this.views = [];
        this.models = [];
        for(var i =0;i<args.items.length;i++)
        {
            this.models[i]      = new BasicContentModel({url:args.items[i].urlRoot+args.items[i].url});
            this.views[i]       = new BasicContentView({model:this.models[i],id:i,className:"tab-"+i});
            this.views[i].bind("updated",this.update,this) //<-- heres the bind
        }
        // blah blah
    },
    update: function(args)
    {
        console.log("updating:",args) //<-- trying to get which one called the update
    }
```

Does this make sense? basically I want to log which view just got updated (bubbling upward sort of thing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I dont think I can delete my question due to lack of points but I've just found the answer elsewhere and thought maybe someone else in future might find this useful:

When you trigger the event the object should be included as the 2nd parameter to the trigger method like so

From BasicContentView

```
this.trigger("updated",this)
```

Answer (score 0):

A collection is the perfect place to do this type of thing, it would be something like this:

```
var myCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.models = [];
    this.collection.add(this.models);
    this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
  }

  addOne: function(model_instance) {
    var basicContentView = new BasicContentView({model:model_instance});
    this.$('ul').append(basicContentView); // if your basicContentView is an li for example.
  }

});
```